# Formatting json response?

Tags: php, json

This is my JSON response:

```
[{"id":"1","company":"india"},{"id":"2","company":"australia"},{"id":"3","company":"srilanka"},{"id":"4","company":"indonasia"}]
```

I want it to be

```
{"results:"[{"id":"1","company":"india"},{"id":"2","company":"australia"},{"id":"3","company":"srilanka"},{"id":"4","company":"indonasia"}] }
```

How can I do it?

PHP code:

```
$q= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM world");

     while($e = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))  
             $output[]=$e;  

     print(json_encode($output));
```

Comment: got it...added following code.$output = json_encode(array('results' => $result));
     print($output);

Answer (score 0):

Its simple `$output['result']=$e`.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$output['result'][]=$e;`.

```
$output = array();
while ($e = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $output['results'][] = $e;
}
print(json_encode($output));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `while`. Try this:

```
$q= mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM world");
$e = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q);
$result = array();
$result['result'] = $e;
print(json_encode($result));
```

Comment: thank you.. I tried following code and it worked for me ...... json_encode(array('results' => $result));